# Rails: end of file reached

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, eof

Working in my Rails development environment, everything peachy, then went away to lunch and now I get "end of file reached" error in browser. Anyone know what's going on?

Here's same response from curl:

````
$ curl http://localhost:7000
EOFError at /
=============

> end of file reached

app/views/application/_javascript.html.slim, line 1
---------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
>   1   = javascript_include_tag :application
    2
    3   = yield :javascript
    4
```

App backtrace
-------------

 - app/views/application/_javascript.html.slim:1:in     `_app_views_application__javascript_html_slim__3196685002532601281_70250473343220'
 - app/views/layouts/full_width.html.slim:24:in `_app_views_layouts_full_width_html_slim___489443475469111239_70110396332180'
 - app/controllers/home_controller.rb:6:in `index'

Full backtrace
--------------

 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load_with_autoloading'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:19:in `block in []'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:19:in `[]'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:14:in `cache_get'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:84:in `cache_get_hash'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:54:in `cache_asset'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
 - sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
 - sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:123:in `asset_digest_path'
 - sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:76:in `compute_asset_path'
 - actionview (4.1.9) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:132:in `asset_path'
 - sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:91:in `asset_path'
````

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If everything was working fine and you didn't make any changes, this could be due to a corrupted tmp cache or Spring being in a bad state. I would try the following from your app's root directory:

1. Stop Spring: `spring stop`
2. Stop your Rails server by pressing `ctrl-c` on your keyboard
3. Clear out your tmp cache by running `bin/rake tmp:clear`
4. Quit and relaunch your Terminal application to make sure nothing is running
5. Start Rails again with `rails s` and try accessing it at http://localhost:3000

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  `$ spring stop` got `Spring is not running` but `bin/rake tmp:clear` did it!

Comment: This was great! `bin/rake tmp:clear` worked for me as well! I was wondering if you could explain a little more about what's actually happening though.  What does the tmp cache do? What can cause it to become corrupted? Why does it being corrupted lead to the end of file error?

Comment: I only ran `bin/rake tmp:clear` and it worked! Thanks!